# Typing commands into SSH has noticeable lag

Tags: server, 20.04, ssh

After I upgraded my home server from an AMD A-series APU to an Intel i7-4790 and did a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 20.04 along with it, I've been getting slight input lag while typing things over SSH. This is most noticeable when writing a lot of text, and deleting text sometimes goes in chunks.

Details:

CPU load hovers at around 20-40%

The server is on an Ethernet connection to the router, with a 500/500 fibre connection to the internet.

Latency is low, with around ~5ms where I am right now. This also happened while I was in the same local network.

I have tried disabling X11 forwaring, UseDNS and enabled TCP KeepAlive in sshd_config

From what I can remember, I didn't have such input lag on my previous setup (AMD A10-7850K, Ubuntu 18.04). What else could I try checking?

Comment: I've seen this happen with an aggressive power saving profile. Disabling power save on the network device may resolve the issue: `iw {device id} set power_save off`. Be sure to replace `{device id}` with your network device ID.

Comment: This returns `command failed: No such device (-19)`, presumably because iw is for wireless adapters, while my network adapter, named eno1, is Ethernet. `iw list` returns nothing as well.

Comment: Yep, I should have included that bit of info. One other option would be to change the `ClientAliveInterval` value in your OpenSSH config file to a value like 15 or 30; something less than the connection timeout.

Comment: Setting it to 15 did not fix my issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by disabling [Intel AMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Active_Management_Technology) on the motherboard.

Comment: Consider that [you might have been pwnd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Active_Management_Technology#Known_vulnerabilities_and_exploits).

Comment: I'm aware, saw something suspicious in the audit logs too. KVM was fortunately broken due to a bug, the server contained no sensitive data, and nothing seems to have been lost. I closed the respective ports on the router too.

Comment: Same problem.

It was my router, in the end.  

I rebooted my router and the issue went away.  Clearly there is something wrong with my router but I don't know what.  This might help someone else.